# How to use HTML code in Wordpress Excerpt

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have been trying to add code to the 'excerpt' section in Wordpress. I basically want to add more elements (and div containers) to give me more flexibility. All the online resources, including the 'Advanced Excerpt' plugin aren't working. I wonder if the problem is that these are all older solutions for Wordpress - I am on 4.9.8. Does anyone know why this might not be working, or how to get this to work? This is the code I have in my functions.php file:

```
function custom_wp_trim_excerpt($text) {
$raw_excerpt = $text;
if ( '' == $text ) {
    $text = get_the_content('');

    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );

    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);

    /***Add the allowed HTML tags separated by a comma.***/
    $allowed_tags = '<p>,<a>,<em>,<strong>,<div>,<b>';  
    $text = strip_tags($text, $allowed_tags);

    /***Change the excerpt word count.***/
    $excerpt_word_count = 60; 
    $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count); 

    /*** Change the excerpt ending.***/
    $excerpt_end = ' <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . '&raquo; Continue Reading.' . '</a>'; 
    $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end);

    $words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if ( count($words) > $excerpt_length ) {
        array_pop($words);
        $text = implode(' ', $words);
        $text = $text . $excerpt_more;
    } else {
        $text = implode(' ', $words);
    }
}
return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

And I tried this...

```
function wpse_allowedtags() {
    // Add custom tags to this string
        return '<script>,<style>,<br>,<em>,<i>,<ul>,<ol>,<li>,<a>,<p>,<img>,<video>,<audio>'; 
    }

if ( ! function_exists( 'wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt' ) ) : 

    function wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($wpse_excerpt) {
    $raw_excerpt = $wpse_excerpt;
        if ( '' == $wpse_excerpt ) {

            $wpse_excerpt = get_the_content('');
            $wpse_excerpt = strip_shortcodes( $wpse_excerpt );
            $wpse_excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $wpse_excerpt);
            $wpse_excerpt = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $wpse_excerpt);

            //Set the excerpt word count and only break after sentence is complete.
                $excerpt_word_count = 75;
                $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count); 
                $tokens = array();
                $excerptOutput = '';
                $count = 0;

                // Divide the string into tokens; HTML tags, or words, followed by any whitespace
                preg_match_all('/(<[^>]+>|[^<>\s]+)\s*/u', $wpse_excerpt, $tokens);

                foreach ($tokens[0] as $token) { 

                    if ($count >= $excerpt_length && preg_match('/[\,\;\?\.\!]\s*$/uS', $token)) { 
                    // Limit reached, continue until , ; ? . or ! occur at the end
                        $excerptOutput .= trim($token);
                        break;
                    }

                    // Add words to complete sentence
                    $count++;

                    // Append what's left of the token
                    $excerptOutput .= $token;
                }

            $wpse_excerpt = trim(force_balance_tags($excerptOutput));

                $excerpt_end = ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;' . sprintf(__( 'Read more about: %s &nbsp;&raquo;', 'wpse' ), get_the_title()) . '</a>'; 
                $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end); 

                //$pos = strrpos($wpse_excerpt, '</');
                //if ($pos !== false)
                // Inside last HTML tag
                //$wpse_excerpt = substr_replace($wpse_excerpt, $excerpt_end, $pos, 0); /* Add read more next to last word */
                //else
                // After the content
                $wpse_excerpt .= $excerpt_more; /*Add read more in new paragraph */

            return $wpse_excerpt;

        }
        return apply_filters('wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt', $wpse_excerpt, $raw_excerpt);
    }

endif; 

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

And this is what I have in the 'excerpt' section for the post:

```
 A new favorite! <strong>From $35pp</strong>
```

The problem is it shows as just that; the code and nothing is in bold. Anyone have any clues? I just have no clue where to go next to get this resolved.

Comment: You have the answers on this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141125/allow-html-in-excerpt

Comment: Tried all that too. And that also does not work.

Comment: Maybe your theme is overwritting your options. Make sure if the theme is adding or removing filters.

Comment: Hmm, that could be possible. Where would I check that?

Comment: Search on all the theme code files 'remove_filter' and 'add_filter' and maybe you can see if is overwritting the excerpt adding or removing filter functions...